# Calculator Subtraction leads to infinite loop

Tags: python, expression, infinite-loop, calculator

I'm working on a calculator which will accept input from the user.
It has to solve expressions such as:

> 1+38*(!2)-5%37

I have been working on the addition and the subtraction but I got into a problem.

I have a loop that is looking for "+" or "-" symbols.
For the "+" it works, but for the "-", whenever I'm solving an expression like

> 1-38

It gets me into an infinite loop since the result of that expression is

> -37

and the loop keeps recognizing the "-" symbol as a subtraction, but as negative 37.

How do I solve this issue?

```
def symbols_exist(exp, symbols_list):
    """ Gets an expression string and a symbols list and returns true if any symbol
        exists in the expression, else returns false. """
    for s in symbols_list:
        if s in exp:
            return True
    return False

def BinaryOperation(exp, idx):
    """ Gets an expression and an index of an operator and returns a tuple with (first_value, operator, second_value). """
    first_value = 0
    second_value = 0

    #Get first value
    idx2 = idx -1
    while (idx2 > 0) and (exp[idx2] in string.digits):
        idx2 -=1

    first_value = exp[idx2:idx]

    #Get second value
    idx2 = idx +1
    while (idx2 < len(exp)) and (exp[idx2] in string.digits):
        idx2 += 1

    second_value = exp[idx+1:idx2]

    return (first_value, exp[idx], second_value)

def solve(exp):
    if not symbols_exist(exp, all_symbols):
        return exp

    idx = 0

    while idx < len(exp):
        if exp[idx] in string.digits:
            #Digit
            idx +=1
        elif exp[idx] in ("+", "-"):
            #Addition and Subtraction
            sub_exp = BinaryOperation(exp, idx)
            if sub_exp[1] == "+":
                value = int(sub_exp[0]) + int(sub_exp[2])
            else:
                value = int(sub_exp[0]) - int(sub_exp[2])

            value = str(value)

            exp = exp.replace(''.join(sub_exp), value)
            print exp

        return solve(exp)
```

Comment: You will need to post some of your code to get help here

Comment: I can't get your programme to work in any case but can't you just change `symbols_exist` so that it removes any initial `-` prior to searching for a symbol? (e.g. `if exp[0] == '-': exp = exp[1:]`)

Comment: It does work but the final line (return solve(exp)) needs to be unindented by 1 tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution that combines the three functions in the original example. (EDIT: just realised the original answer I posted could be simplified quite a bit)

```
all_symbols = '+-'
def solve(expres):
    lhs, symbol, rhs = expres[0], None, ''
    for ch in expres[1:]:
        if symbol:
            rhs += ch
        elif ch in all_symbols:
            symbol = ch
        else:
            lhs += ch
    if symbol is '+':
        return int(lhs) + solve(rhs)
    if symbol is '-':
        return int(lhs) - solve(rhs)
    return int(expres)

print solve('1+5')
```

And another type of solution that may be useful to consider

```
operations = [
    ('+', lambda a, b: a + b),
    ('-', lambda a, b: a - b)
    ]
def solve(exp):
    for symbol, operation in operations:
        p = exp.rfind(symbol)
        if p > 0:
            return operation(solve(exp[:p]), solve(exp[p + 1:]))
    return int(exp)
```

Comment: I have been trying to do this using recursion, that's why I designed different functions.
What I'm trying to do is to solve the "strongest" operators in the expression, then call again the solve() with an updated expression which will contain the solved operators (which are the strongest, for example power is strongest than multiplication and multiplication is strongest than addition or subtraction),

Comment: and the recursion will keep calling itself until all of the expression will become numeric without any symbols (that's why the base condition of the solve() function is checking whether there are more symbols or not in the expression).

Comment: This suggestion also uses recursion in exactly the way you describe and can be adapted to solve the strongest operators first. Either way, all you need to do is ignore an initial '-' when checking for symbols within the expression, which this suggestion achieves with `if ch in all_symbols and n:` and see my comment on your question for how to do the same in your original programme.